# Typescript index type composition

Tags: typescript, generics, indexing, types, composition

I am trying to type my event API as such:

```
type Apple = {
    seeds: number;
}
type Peach = {
    weight: number;
}

interface AddAppleEvent {
    apple: Apple;
}

interface AddPeachEvent {
    peach: Peach;
}

interface EventMap {
    "addApple": AddAppleEvent;
    "addPeach": AddPeachEvent;
}


class EventApi{
    on<K extends keyof EventMap>(type: K, listener: (ev: EventMap[K]) => any): void{    
    }
}

const api = new EventApi();
api.on("addApple", (evt) => {
    console.log(evt.apple);
});
```

This works wonder: Typescript knows what is in my **evt** variable from the name of the event I am registering on.

**But**: I would like ot be able to register to **an array** of events, and type the result (which will be a composition of the types of each events):

```
api.on(["addApple", "addPeach"], ({apple, peach}) => {
    if(apple) {
     // do something
    }
    if(peach) {
     // do something else
    }

})
```

Unfortunately I cant find a way to iterate over an array of keys from an interface to build an union of all the values referred.

Any idea ?

[Here is a link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAghCAbWBeGBvYMcwM5RQAmeAXDAHYCuAtgEZQBOA3MAL6iSwAKUAhgGMAFjHRZcMAO5QAlgHMhIctXpNWHYDIogmAM0Gw4RIgmRQAogDco2zNlx9EKcqZTrgm7XoPxjvQUJWNiB2EtAB5P7C7p46jPoCsEHaALKOobgARHzGrlCZLrlOFtbarBLZfvzCBb5EUYGlIDHAAkh8eHgwySAIMlj2OAD2FAA8ANIwUAAeOhQkMADWUGBDut1NaRAAfAAU4NDk4wA0MEgyeHNM5LtQluQ9WwDa4wC6AJSi2zB8FGDv5EsQxkRHEElwg3BAhGeCGKAAdEghnJdpkRj9jFMmmcLnMKExMqdzpcbEx3uVcBwJJCAPQ0mBCJhQU6SRgyHQwSYdH74KAhNZLFZdXSMIY0DbBLY-JBIyRdEBDGAQDpdGhUJAgGRmQVgPDHWn0uhUEIASRgAl%20IV0WiIDKGkhgCsdXEdjJxJPxjCVougjBlYHhkJGKXVmrMEyerymsxsC2Wq3Wj0cewOUCORNxpMYNzuD02jheHy%20Pz%20AJgQJBGXB5phcKgiORqPROVtao1WpQWOC7rxBIzHrJFJwGg00Iolx%20EBkokoUAdPT6u3JwEcMnhI1RLbyhJgt0sIE%20qG%20YJwY9hCKRKLuIHhjjMy7Yy5XU-XFBD7bMuyelRMxR3P4aTJXlOPcD2LE8a3HOsGyvfdb2KU5r3hcJhHedg0JwDwcCAA) to the typescript playground with the example above

-----**EDIT**----

Just summing up the great answers I got for this post:

- If you want **union**: [checkout this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAghCAbWBeGBvYMcwM5RQAmeAXDAHYCuAtgEZQBOA3MAL6iSwAKUAhgGMAFjHRZcMAO5QAlgHMhIctXpNWHcNBi8%20jUZmy4AZjMY0KUPGUq0GLGAHoHMACJUKFAPYAafJ5pQIEIyFHLswMAhIExGgrBwREQIyFAAogBuUBQgBhJ8iCjkySisEtLyiqQAjOoRUTFx8Ik6whlZOeK40IJC5C1CpbjlCkoATLWR2Q0C8c38jG3ZuV3zffODOMOVAMwT9YyxMzCLIACy%20cs4AER8icVQV0V3BWmZ2RswN3M9j01E-ScPl9-vNfn8dAs3iAJppYCdzhAANJQMD6ADWKM8RmOUIRrGAAiQfCsOPaCBkWEMOE8FAAPIiYFAAB7RCgkUnZBHIsAAPgAFLDyIjfEgZHhWUxyHyoOlyPD8gBtREAXQAlKIeTA%20BQwKryOlPDIiJ0JDgqaaBDS8J4UAA6JCeOR8q40rWJRlQmCi8VZCyMK4isUSxiqj4cCTmpwwIRMKC%20SSMGTRGAM4la-CBGBYmAYsB4GBGRj%20DlnC58JAOyT5kCeGAQYn5mhUJAgGQpHMovDeSPOOhUHIASRgAm1ORMbOjnkkMBrM64M5jXqDWSYdaL0EYFbAtvNNNOzdbKXpjJZWXZ8qRKIVyt8JwAKvPmazz7jFYiFSo7MrlfzBSnAz6fpSjKcpQg%200Dqqgmrarq%20qGkQlwWlaNpQPajrOq6twIU2LZtigHrtEugF%20gGRHBqG5ocOEBJWjk%20QyPoFjTic5J8hR9G2jSzpYfcpHSukICQZqJrDshdoOk6MogLa%20QpBRbAUcAUYABKxr4UkwGKfz3CcMAAD7gvwrRQsAHF7geeFQHyCrArxvjAv0Vw3jA-GCRqiGWhQ1riehUm2lsgnsKGQA) by @t-j-crowder
- If you want **intersection**: checkout [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAghCAbWBeGBvYMcwM5RQAmeAXDAHYCuAtgEZQBOA3MAL6iSwAKUAhgGMAFjHRZcMAO5QAlgHMhIctXpNWHcNBi8%20jUZmy4AZjMY0KUPGUq0GLGAHoHMACJUKFAPYAafJ5pQIEIyFHLswMAhIExGgrBwREQIyFAAogBuUBQgBhJ8iCjkySjqEVExcfCJOsIZWTniuNCCQuQ1QqWR2RUC8dX8jHXZuU0DbQOd5YyxvTBDIACy%20SM4AER8icVQq0WbBWmZ2awS6-0tO1VE7fPHuKdXAxcJD7o34Zxa80sQANJQYPoANb-TxGOaHRb5VgRTSwADC-ggngIRHmABkZHhohZGAAeH4wKAAD2xJHB9W%20fzAAG0ALoAPn0jRw1IAkjAQjBgWBQTAfrTyAAKKDpchffLU1IkxiCED4tm03zi37-em0gCUokZfAoYHY1JUdlphJJWTJwtFHIoRiYMFZmtQ2t1MAA-DALeR7VqYDqAcoRUwIgIkHwrOTsggZAZDDhPBR8SbSXhw5CVWB6YLYeQfr4kJjsUwhSKxRDvtT%20Q6nWB1eR0p4ZERoxIJAI43hPCgAHRITxyQWrOM%20xKEiEwPNYrI41a5-NZJjq244DgxxzOIRMKC%20SSMGTRPk%205N8fCBGC87nJoyMfwp74%20pA9yTJkCeGAQUPJmhUJAgGQpLn-PBvBXJwYDoKgcnZAQdRyEwKEbIRPEkGBn2QrhkPXMdZxxV8r2gRh7zATsVzjBYvx-FIE2JJMb3yKk6QzLMYEYfgiDjJAAWpTsuP5GcJxxcgERoJEUXRLCmHxekaxgOsGxWZtWwodsux7PsBwoIdG0-b9fxQEd6kwvip14gtGAXFdl2XBSsR9CAo3QCwkPmSNBTM-IZE7ON%20w2JJ9mnd0RRASs5KsjsoG7XsLRATt8hSMy2DM4AQIACQ3XwAo5Q89j-ANhgAMg09o9OyYA3I8ihSO0lJBWpe4tj8%2052lWRV-PSQLvQwGAVxC5SIoC6L9jS1rO2aYR1XYBcgA) by @jcalz

Thanks a lot guys:)

Comment: Welcome to SO! The site says this is your first question here. You've done a great job on it! Nice one!

Comment: Do you want the event in your multiple usage to be `AddAppleEvent | AddPeachEvent` (a union, as in your text), or `AddAppleEvent & AddPeachEvent` (an intersection)? The example usage at the end of the question above looks like an intersection, but you've said "union" in the text and that's what seems to make sense...

Comment: Thanks guys :) . Actually you are right, I want the intersection :), but you guys area such machines that you already produced an answer for both cases :boom:
Thanks a lot for your time guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by defining `EventMapKey` just to avoid retyping `keyof EventMap`:

```typescript
type EventMapKey = keyof EventMap;
```

Then it depends on whether you want a union or an intersection.

#### Union

You can define `onMultiple` like this:

```
onMultiple<K extends EventMapKey[], EventType extends EventMap[K[number]]>(type: K, listener: (ev: EventType) => any): void {
    console.log("on add multiple event listenner", listener);
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAghCAbWBeGBvYMcwM5RQAmeAXDAHYCuAtgEZQBOA3MAL6iSwAKUAhgGMAFjHRZcMAO5QAlgHMhIctXpNWHcNBi8%20jUZmy4AZjMY0KUPGUq0GLGAHoHMACJUKFAPYAafJ5pQIEIyFHLswMAhIExGgrBwREQIyFAAogBuUBQgBhJ8iCjkySjqEVExcfCJOsIZWTniuNCCQuQ1QqWR2RUC8dX8jHXZuU0DbQOd5YyxvTBDIACy%20SM4AER8icVQq0WbBWmZ2awS6-0tO1VE7fPHuKdXAxeXOoOHIJ2asPNLEADSUGB9ABrAGeIxzN4-VjAARIPhWCH1BAyLCGHCeCgAHl%20MCgAA9ohQSIjsj9-mAAHwACk%205F%20viQMjwhKY5CpUHS5G%20%20QA2r8ALoASlEFJgfAoYEF5HSnhkREaEhwaMVAgxeE8KAAdEhPHIqasMWLEri3jBGcyshZGKsGUyWYxBbccBwJMqnDAhEwoL5JIwZNEYDj4WL8IEYGCYCCwHgYEZGP4SYtlnwkDrJDGQJ4YBB4TGaFQkCAZClIwC8N43c46FQcgBJGACcU5ExEj2eSQwTOdridz1mu1ZJjZ%20PQRipsCa5UYhYFospbG4glZYncv4Ann83zzAAqPfxhJXkN5vx5Kjs-P51NpgdtFqtbI5XLeu%20gwtQovFkulsqIKxVao1KBtV1fVDQ2X980LYsUBNep%20zvK0bXg%201HWVDhwhhNUcnyGR9AsDt5mRKlUJwzUMX1cCtiQ9l0hAN9RQVBsAK1HU9Q5EBNXyFJULYVDgFI6dZ2gqAqR5e4qN8e52lWTcYBouiRT-d0AAkvV8diYCZS4tnmGAAB9nn4Wo3nYR0gA) - I added a third event type (just to be sure), and the example usage of `onMultiple` at the end works:

```typescript
api.onMultiple(["addApple", "addPeach"], (evt) => {
    // Here, evt is AddAppleEvent | AddPeachEvent
});
```

Naturally, before you can use the `apple` or `peach` properties of `evt`, you have to do a type guard to check what kind of event you're dealing with. To aid with that, I'd probably add a `type` to the event types so you can work from that:

```typescript
interface AddAppleEvent {
    type: "addApple";
    apple: Apple;
}

interface AddPeachEvent {
    type: "addPeach";
    peach: Peach;
}

api.onMultiple(["addApple", "addPeach"], (evt) => {
    if (evt.type === "addApple") {
        console.log(evt.apple.seeds);
    } else {
        console.log(evt.peach.weight);
    }
});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAghCAbWBeGBvYMcwM5RQAmeAXDAHYCuAtgEZQBOA3MAL6iSwAKUAhgGMAFjHRZcMAO5QAlgHMhIctXpNWHcNBi8+jUZmy4AZjMY0KUPGUq0GLGAHoHMACJUKFAPYAafJ5pQIEIyFHLswMAhIExGgrBwREQIyFAAogBuUBQgBhKaUOQARHyJySiFrBJ8iCjkZVDqEVExcfCJOsIZWTniuPlFJUQdQhWGONCCQuTDjZHZLQLx7fyMXdm5fVwDy7qjEhOM0yuzzYyxizBrIACy1Rs4xaU1UIV1TylXlbiPQ-zCr21fpNPmMYD8dIwAYCISCOJwtFdbhAANJQMD6ADWaM8RkumWySNYwAESD4Vjx3QQMiwoM8FAAPMiYFAAB7RCgkCkE6qosAAPgAFP0YMjfEgZHh2UxyAKoOlyIjqgBtZEAXQAlKI+TA+BQwOryOlPDIiL0JDhQRIBHS8J4UAA6JCeOQCwp0nWJZn4nLiyVZCyQsUSqWMdVfHAcCSgpwwIRMKC+SSMGTREU6vA6-CBGA4mBYsAZoyMfxcm53PhIJ2SDMgTwwCBkjM0KhIEAyFJ5tF4bzR5x0Kg5ACSMAEupyJg5sc8khgtdnXFncZgvpD9eL0EYlbA9tpFGuLbbKUZzLZWU5ipRaKVqt8VwAKgvWezz96kSqlSo7KrVYLhaLl8GWTSjAsryqWD7QJqqDarq+qGsaRD3Oa1oULaDpOi6boUB6iHNq27YoF63QAX6HhMIUQakUwYagnCcIoZKOoQDI+gWDOVxUgKNHVDI9p0q6gz1BRIFyiAUHamaI42naUCOs6oEgPa1QpDRbA0cAPF8XuB4EVAApKj8Qm+OCfwjDeInpGJWpITIuIKfa+SiKg6CGc8hSapJVrSeh8miUpzz2gQxB4DREhsMySAEEhXmoTJckun5EzCPa0jyIooW4BwanMEAA)

But you can also work from `"apple" in evt` without adding `type` if you like.

```
api.onMultiple(["addApple", "addPeach"], (evt) => {
    if ("apple" in evt) {
        console.log(evt.apple.seeds);
    } else {
        console.log(evt.peach.weight);
    }
});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAghCAbWBeGBvYMcwM5RQAmeAXDAHYCuAtgEZQBOA3MAL6iSwAKUAhgGMAFjHRZcMAO5QAlgHMhIctXpNWHcNBi8+jUZmy4AZjMY0KUPGUq0GLGAHoHMACJUKFAPYAafJ5pQIEIyFHLswMAhIExGgrBwREQIyFAAogBuUBQgBhJ8iCjkySjqEVExcfCJOsIZWTniuNCCQuQ1QqWR2RUC8dX8jHXZuU0DbQOd5YyxvTBDIACy+SM4AER8icVQq0WbBWmZ2awS6-0tO1VE7fPHuKdXAxeXOoOHIJ2asPNLEADSUGB9ABrAGeIxzN4-VjAARIPhWCH1BAyLCGHCeCgAHl+MCgAA9ohQSIjsj9-mAAHwACk+5F+viQMjwhKY5CpUHS5G++QA2r8ALoASlEFJgfAoYEF5HSnhkREaEhwaMVAgxeE8KAAdEhPHIqasMWLEri3jBGcyshZGKsGUyWYxBbccBwJMqnDAhEwoL5JIwZNEYDj4WL8IEYGCYCCwHgYEZGP4SYtlnwkDrJDGQJ4YBB4TGaFQkCAZClIwC8N43c46FQcgBJGACcU5ExEj2eSQwTOdridz1mu1ZJjZ+PQRipsCa5UYhYFospbG4glZYncv4Ann83zzAAqPfxhJXkN5vx5Kjs-P51NpgdtFqtbI5XLeu+gwtQovFkulsqIKxVao1KBtV1fVDQ2X980LYsUBNep+zvK0bXg+1HWVDhwhhNUcnyGR9AsDt5mRKlUJwzUMX1cCtiQ9l0hAN9RQVBsAK1HU9Q5EBNXyFJULYVDgFI6dZ2gqAqR5e4qN8e52lWTcYBouiRT-GRwQo-ZVhgEITQUxiJFVCh1RYkD2M4-ZNQIYg8FQiQ2FxJACD-XTmKA1j5M1ZphE1aR5EUKzcA4XjWCAA)

#### Intersection

If you want an intersection instead, here's the solution [jcalz posted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68893678/typescript-index-type-composition#comment121756786_68893843):

```typescript
type ComposedEventListener<K extends EventMapKey[]> = {
    [I in keyof K]: (ev: EventMap[Extract<K[I], EventMapKey>]) => any
}[number] extends (ev: infer I) => any ? (ev: I) => any : never

class EventApi {

    on<K extends EventMapKey>(type: K, listener: (ev: EventMap[K]) => any): void {

        console.log("on add event listenner", listener);
    }

    // here, write K as a set of keys from EventMap allows to pass multiple keys,
    // but I cant find how to type the listener properlly.
    onMultiple<K extends EventMapKey[]>(type: readonly [...K], listener: ComposedEventListener<K>): void {
        console.log("on add multiple event listenner", listener);
    }

}

const api = new EventApi();
api.on("addApple", (evt) => {
    console.log(evt.apple);
});

api.onMultiple(["addApple", "addPeach"], (evt) => { });
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=29&ssc=1&pln=55&pc=56#code/C4TwDgpgBAgmYBtoF4oG8BQVtQM4QgBNcAuKAOwFcBbAIwgCcBuDAXw1EigAUIBDAMYALKKkw4oAdwgBLAOZDgZKnUYt2naLz4NR6LDgBmMhtXIRcpCjXrMoAentQAIpXLkA9gBo8H6hGAhGXI5NgwMYOBGQ0FoGEJCOEQIAFEANwhyYH0JPngkMiSkdXDI6NjYBO1hdMzs8RxIQSEyaqESiKzygTiq-gZarJzG-tb+jrKGGJ6oQeAAWTzh7AAiPgSiiBXCjfzUjKyWCTW+5u3Kwja5o5wTy-7z+Puda7COcGg5xbAAaQgQPQAa3+HkMswOCzyLHeXAAwn4wB58IQ5gAZGS4KLmBgAHh+UAgAA8scRwXVvn8QABtAC6AD49A1sFSAJJQYJQYEgUFQH40sgACggaTIXzyVJSxIYgmAeNZNJ8Yt+-zpNIAlKIGXxyCA2FSVLYaQTiZlSUKRezyIZGFAWRrkFqdVAAPxQc1kO2aqDagHKYWMcICBB8SxkrJwGT6AzYDzkPHGkm4MOQ5UgOkCzRkH4+BAYrGMQXC0UQ75Uvn2x0gNVkNIeGSEKMSCQCWO4DxIAB0CA8cgFK1j3oSBIhUFzmMy2JWObzmUYapu2HY0YcTiEjAgPkkDBkUV53qTfDwASgPK5ScMDD8ye+3oQ3ckSeAHigYBDSeolAQwBkyU5-1wXjLo4UC0JQ2RsgI2rZMY5ANkIHiSFAT5IR8SFrqOM7Yi+l6QAwd4gB2y6xvMn7fsk8ZEom155JStLppmUAMPwhCxggAJUh2nF8tO47YmQ8LUIiyJophjB4nS1ZQLW9bLE2LbkG2nbdr2-bkIODYfl+P5IMOdQYbxk48fmDDzsuS5LvJmLemAkaoOYiFzBGAqmXkMgdrGfbrIkexTm6wrABWsmWe2EBdj25rAB2eTJKZrCmRgrnueQJFackApUncmy+XcbQrAqflpAFXpoFAcVMEAA)

Comment: Isn't the question asking for `evt` to be `AddAppleEvent & AddPeachEvent` instead of `AddPeachEvent | AddPeachEvent`?

Comment: @jcalz - The OP said "union" (*"... I cant find a way to iterate over an array of keys from an interface to build an union of all the values referred..."*) so I figured they wanted a union. The usage in the handler does look like an intersection usage granted; I just figured that was not realizing they needed the guard. (Their multiple event usage also differed in the playground vs. the question, I just realized.)

Comment: If the OP *does* want an intersection then it needs to look something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WK8KDw) instead, fwiw

Comment: @jcalz - !  *Way* out of my league there. 

Comment: @jcalz - You were right, they wanted an intersection, not a union, if you feel like posting an answer. (I'm not qualified to describe your playground link above.  )